# is it possible to make money from Token transaction fees?

Tags: token, fees

it is possible te deduct commission when from the token used for every transaction.
let's assume the token name is "Xtoken"
User "A" send  "1000 Xtoken" to user "B", the stellar network will deduct transaction fees from my stellar source account,
I want to get "1 Xtoken" for every transaction and send it to my "Xtoken" wallet.
These additional fees will be paid by the sender.
is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

One workarounds for this case is:

Set "authorization required" for your asset but don't allowTrust to any user in general. Instead require them to sandwich every payment + payment fee operation between a allowTrust and a allowTrust(revoke) operation. This way your authorization (by co-signing every transaction with the asset issuer account) for using that asset is only granted temporarily within this atomic transaction.

Altough there is [SEP-8](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol/blob/master/ecosystem/sep-0008.md) showing a standardized way to automate the co-signing process, afaik there is yet no wallet around that implements it. You'll have to code your own wallet and co-signing service.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible on Stellar currently. There are several protocol changes proposals that may allow addressing such logic in the future, but I doubt that we'll see it on the mainnet anytime soon.

Comment: thanks, i hope so

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Imagine I Want to Tokenize Shares/Commodities but Not Build My Own Exchange to Allow Commissions. But Rather Collect 0.5% of Every SDEX Transaction of Issued Tkns. The Seller Sells Bob 100 Tkns & Bob Receives 99.5; The Issuer of Tkns Receives 0.5 Tkns.

I'm Thinking of a Way Some Investment House Would Incentivised to Issue Equity backed Tokens to be Traded on SDEX. Those Starting on this Task Are Establishing Their Own Exchanges That Do Not Contribute to Stellar Volume & Their Tokens Will NOT be Accessible on SDEX / StellarX etc.